# Shared memory to stdout does not output anything in C

Tags: c, memory, stdout, shared, stderr

I am trying to send a file from parent process to two child processes and children write file to two seperate shared memories, after that parent will read shared memories and output results to stdout and stderr. However, after some run, my program started not to give output. literally nothing is printed, no error messages or something else. I cannot figure out why.

I run my code as:

```
./myprogram >out.txt 2>out2.txt
```

But both files are empty.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHM_NAME_1 "SHM1"
#define SHM_NAME_2 "SHM2"
#define FIFO_1 "FIFO1"
#define FIFO_2 "FIFO2"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 65536 // 64 KB
#define MEM_SIZE 2097152 // 2 MB


void stringtohex(char* input, char* output)
{
    int loop;
    int i; 

    i=0;
    loop=0;

    while(input[loop] != '\0')
    {
        sprintf((char*)(output+i),"%02X", input[loop]);
        loop+=1;
        i+=2;
    }
    //insert NULL at the end of the output string
    output[i++] = '\0';
}

int main(){

    pid_t pid,pid_2;
    FILE *file;
    char *infile = "input.txt";

    pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pid > 0){ // parent

        pid_2 = fork();

        if(pid_2 > 0){ // parent

            file = fopen(infile, "r");

            if(file == 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "File failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
            // close read end of pipe
            mknod(FIFO_1, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
            mknod(FIFO_2, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

            int fd = open(FIFO_1, O_WRONLY);
            int sd = open(FIFO_2, O_WRONLY);

            char str[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while(fgets(str, BUFFER_SIZE, file) > 0)
            {
                // write all lines of file
                write(fd, str, strlen(str));
                write(sd, str, strlen(str));
            }
            // send EOF explicitly
            write(fd, "\0", 1);
            write(sd, "\0", 1);
            // close file and pipes
            close(fd);
            close(sd);
            fclose(file);
            // wait for child to write to shared memory
            wait(NULL);

            // open shared segments
            int shm_first = shm_open(SHM_NAME_1, O_RDONLY, 0666);
            int shm_second = shm_open(SHM_NAME_2, O_RDONLY, 0666);

            if (shm_first == -1 || shm_second == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed: Shared Memory 1");
                exit(-1);
            }

            // create memory pointers
            void *ptr = mmap(0,MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_first, 0);
            void *ptr2 = mmap(0,MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_second, 0);

            if (ptr == MAP_FAILED || ptr2 == MAP_FAILED) {
                printf("Map failed 1\n");
                return -1;
            }

            // print out results and unlink shared segments
            fprintf(stdout, "Normal ouput: \n%s\n", ptr);
            fprintf(stderr, "Hexadecimal output: \n%s\n", ptr2);

            shm_unlink(SHM_NAME_1);
            shm_unlink(SHM_NAME_2);

        } else {

            int shm_child_2 = shm_open(SHM_NAME_2, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

            // configure the size of the shared memory segment 
            ftruncate(shm_child_2,MEM_SIZE);
            // map the pointer to the segment
            void *ptr_child_2 = mmap(0,MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_child_2, 0);

            if (ptr_child_2 == MAP_FAILED) 
            {
                printf("Map failed in second child\n");
                return -1;
            }

            mknod(FIFO_2, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
            int fd = open(FIFO_2, O_RDONLY);

            int num;
            char s[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while((num = read(fd, s, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
            {     
                char hex[num*2];
                stringtohex(s, hex);
                sprintf(ptr_child_2, "%s", hex);
                ptr_child_2 += num*2;
            }

            close(fd);
            exit(0);
        }

    } else { // child

        // create the shared segment for the first time
        int shm_child_1 = shm_open(SHM_NAME_1, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);

        // configure the size of the shared memory segment 
        ftruncate(shm_child_1,MEM_SIZE);
        // map the pointer to the segment
        void *ptr_child_1 = mmap(0,MEM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_child_1, 0);

        if (ptr_child_1 == MAP_FAILED) 
        {
            printf("Map failed in first child\n");
            return -1;
        }


        mknod(FIFO_1, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
        int fd = open(FIFO_1, O_RDONLY);

        int num;
        char s[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while((num = read(fd, s, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {     
            sprintf(ptr_child_1, "%s", s);
            ptr_child_1 += num;
        }

        close(fd);
        exit(0);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the call to `stringtohex`, the input `s` is not null terminated and the output array `hex` does not have room for the null terminator at the end.

Comment: But then, why the normal output is not present? that function is called only in the second child